# JQuery: How to make same class option selected

Tags: jquery, html-select

My html have mutliple drop down box with same class.
I am getting a value from each input box and then pass it to `<select>` as selector. The value i am getting is correct from input box but I am having trouble in making my drop down box selected.

HTML:

```
<div id="orange">
    <input type="text" class="hide" value="AM" />
    <select class="ampm">
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="PM">PM</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="hide" value="AM" />
    <select class="ampm">
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="PM">PM</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="hide" value="PM" />
    <select class="ampm">
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="PM">PM</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="apple">
    <input type="text" class="hide" value="AM" />
    <select class="ampm">
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="PM">PM</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="hide" value="PM" />
    <select class="ampm">
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="PM">PM</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.hide').each(function () { //inputbox
         $(this).find('.ampm').val($(this).val()); //option                        
         alert($(this).val());
     });    
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle FullCode](http://jsfiddle.net/LpsVn/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` looks **within** the element.  Your select box is not contained within your input, so nothing is found.  Instead change it to `next`:

```
     $(this).next('.ampm').val($(this).val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpsVn/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function () {
        $('div .hide').each(function () {
             $(this).next('.ampm').val($(this).val());                         
             console.log($(this).val());
         });    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LpsVn/5/).

For a much cool solution you can look at the comment by @wirey

```
$(function() {
    $('div .ampm').val(function() {
                return $(this).prev('.hide').val();
            })
});
```

Comment: it can be reduced even more by using .val(function  `$(function () {
    $('div .ampm').val(function () {
        return $(this).prev('.hide').val();
    })
});`

Comment: that's cool but a problem with code like that though, is that it breaks if you put stuff in the middle.  I think starting from the parent div and grabbing each is a little less brittle

Comment: @David since all the answers given here depends on `next()` it is a given, else we have to either use `siblings('.ampm')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, see mine below again.  You can put elements in the middle or flip the order and it wouldn't matter, because I use the $div as the starting point.  Anyway, it's a subtle point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('div').each(function() {
        var $div = $(this);
        $div.find('.hide').change(function() {  //inputs change:
            var newInputVal = $(this).val();
            $div.find('.ampm').val(newInputVal);
        });
    });
});
```

note this changes in groups.  That is however many .ampm are in the parent div.  Not sure that's what you intended.  A little late to this, but tried to make it clear with the variables for beginners.  The next() alternative above, *might* be a little brittle in some cases.  Also, I think there are some obvious concerns with this in general like when the blur is actually fired etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpsVn/

Comment: if you look carefully, every `div` has to `ampm` and `hide` elements

Comment: I'm just trying to take into account futureproofing.

Answer (score 0):

You were iterating through select tags inside input tags which is not possible since select tags are not children of input. So what you can do is just iterate through input tags and then find its next sibling select tag and assign it the value of current input tag.

```
$(function () {
$('div').find('input').each(function(){                
alert( $(this).val());
$(this).next('select').val($(this).val());
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpsVn/8/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("select option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == text1; 
}).attr('selected', true);
```

Filter for the correct option and set the `selected` attribute to true.

Comment: This is a really convoluted way to do exactly the same thing as just calling `.val`

Comment: not really. In a large select you will see the performance difference.

Comment: Even if that is the case, this question is trying to set a specific select, not every select.

Comment: That's right it is. Your answer works wonderfully. I take a different approach and write things I can scale and won't break if something is changed. For instance, if the class or id of the element changes in the future it won't break all your code. It should also be noted that .val() won't work if the value attribute isn't set (jquery 1.4.x)

Comment: can you set up a jsperf that proves this? (I didn't vote you down, but would be kind of curious heh)

Comment: When I get to my computer. On phone at the moment. In a select, options do not have a value unless the value attribute is set. jQuery will return null. (In this question the value attribute is set. I just always code for scalability and flexibility)